# how to restore public_html folder in cpanel?

Tags: linux, web-server

> I have accidentally deleted **public_html** folder in cpanel. I don't
>   have local backup of public_html folder.
>   How can I recover my files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without backup you can't restore public_html, If you have purchase hosting you need to ask for backup of your domain, then untar backup anywhere else and move public_html to its location.